# DataError when creating an index with a compound key in IE 10

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am testing an indexedDB based app using IE10. I am not able to create an object store which has multiple keys. For example, `var objectStore = theDb.createObjectStore("store1", { keyPath: ["key1","key2"] });`.

When I try to insert data into the store an exception message is raised: "DataError" This is not very helpful! Has anyone been able to create `objectStores` using IE10 with multiple keys? This works fine testing in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for showing a Chrome user how to do it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I run into the same problem. From their forum thread, complex key path or compound index [not supported](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/dbf2fd2d-a8ca-4228-8a49-3948d44f7e26/) in IE10 complaining that spec was not defined (incorrect). There are other IndexedDB API features not implemented in IE10. To be fair, IE10 IndexedDB is fast.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have managed to create compound indexes in IE10 its only an issue with complex keys. I agree that IE10 is fast using indexedDB and generally they have done a pretty good job if it.

Comment: Really. I though IE10 don't have compound indexing. Complex key, as I understand means `keyPath: 'userid.email'`, whereas compound index is as in your example, but keyPath of index.

Comment: Ok so we are talking slightly different things. In my initial example I use 2 fields for the key. This fails. (var objectStore = theDb.createObjectStore("store1", { keyPath: ["key1","key2"] });) However if I use multiple fields in an index it is fine. e.g. objectStore.createIndex("multipleIndex", ["field1","field2"], { unique: true });

Comment: Why would you like to do this. The thing you are now trying to implement isn't described in the IndexedDB API. Meaning you are now trying things that are not supported, so the chance is high that other browsers won't support it and chrome won't implement it in the future. I would look for an other way to implement the logic you want.

Comment: I want a composite key on an object store. This is from the specification: If keyPath is an Array, then each item in the array is converted to a string. If keyPath is not an Array, it is converted to a string. Why would an array be passed into a keyPath unless it was meant to allow multiple keys?

If keyPath is an Array and any items in the array is not a valid key path, or if keyPath is a string and is not a valid key path then a DOMException of type SyntaxError must be thrown. Otherwise set the created object store's key path is set to the value of keyPath.

Comment: I am from an SQL based background, am still trying to understand indexedDB, so I am interested to find out how we can handle a data example like firstname and lastname in indexedDB. E.g. firstname and lastname are unique. But firstname OR lastname could be replicated. If we can only setup a single key for the objectstore we can never add users with the same firstname or lastname. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think what you are doing is the right way. Alternatively, without using composite keyPath, you can use key value of an array, i.e, the key value is ['first', 'last']. But it doesn't work in IE10 now. Interesting relevant historical discussion http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2010OctDec/0823.html

Comment: I got idea. Why not use unique compound index as effective key? Let the primary key be out-of-line and auto generated.

Comment: Thanks Kyaw. That is what I intend to do for now.

Comment: I can confirm that IE 10+11 still don't accept complex keys, as of January 2014.  [Here's a gist to demonstrate.](https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/8330172).